# Why is the rationale to forward declare and define in the same header?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm learning QT and when I create a project this is the header of the widget class:

```
#ifndef NOTEPAD_H
#define NOTEPAD_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class Notepad;
}

class Notepad : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit Notepad(QWidget *parent = 0);
~Notepad();

private:
Ui::Notepad *ui;
};

#endif // NOTEPAD_H
```

Why not just define the class inside the namespace scope? Is this a best practice stuff?

Answer (score 4):

This code is forward declaring `Ui::Notepad`, then defining `::Notepad`. **They are not the same type**, despite having the same name (which is a silly decision in itself).